# Select data from a table and fill in the columns in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table (tbTest):

| id_main | operation | id_cli | name | dueDate | value | debtShare | address | id_parcel | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 253 | 66 | 9876 | Johnny | 2018-11-01 | 1.2 | 1 | abc street 12 | 7197 |  |  |  |  |  | N |
| 253 | 67 | 9876 | Johnny | 2018-11-01 | 3.7 | 4 | abc street 12 | 7198 |  |  |  |  |  | N |
| 254 | 68 | 9876 | Johnny | 2017-11-20 | 7.8 | 1 | abc street 12 | 4196 |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 254 | 68 | 9876 | Johnny | 2015-11-20 | 9.3 | 1 | abc street 12 | 4670 |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 254 | 68 | 9876 | Johnny | 2020-12-22 | 6.0 | 1 | abc street 12 | 5235 |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 254 | 68 | 9876 | Johnny | 2016-09-20 | 9.2 | 1 | abc street 12 | 7199 |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 254 | 68 | 5432 | David | 2017-11-20 | 7.8 | 2 | axe avenue 46 | 4196 |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 254 | 68 | 5432 | David | 2015-11-20 | 9.3 | 2 | axe avenue 46 | 4670 |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 254 | 68 | 5432 | David | 2020-12-22 | 6.0 | 2 | axe avenue 46 | 5235 |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 254 | 68 | 5432 | David | 2016-09-20 | 9.2 | 2 | axe avenue 46 | 7199 |  |  |  |  |  | Y |

I'm trying to build a query to get the following result:

```
id_main|operation|id_cli|name  |dueDate   |value|debtShare|address      |id_parcel|d1        |d2        |d3        |d4        |d5|Type|
    253|       66|  9876|Johnny|2018-11-01|  1.2|        1|abc street 12|     7197|2018-11-01|          |          |          |  |N   |
    253|       67|  9876|Johnny|2018-11-01|  3.7|        4|abc street 12|     7198|2018-11-01|          |          |          |  |N   |
    254|       68|  9876|Johnny|2015-11-20|  9.3|        1|abc street 12|     4670|2015-11-20|2016-09-20|2017-11-20|2020-12-22|  |Y   |
    254|       68|  5432|David |2015-11-20|  9.3|        2|axe avenue 46|     4670|2015-11-20|2016-09-20|2017-11-20|2020-12-22|  |Y   |
```

In this table, when Type=Y, the dueDate value goes to columns d1, d2 etc, ordered by date; and when Type=N, there is only one dueDate value, which goes to column d1.

I've searched and found a (not so) [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738066/how-to-select-multiple-rows-in-sql-server-while-filling-one-column-with-the-firs).
Based on it, I've tried to do what I need, but have no success.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2144b6/5

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for setting up the data in Fiddle. I don't understand the logical requirement, though. How are the dates in the `d*` columns derived?

Comment: Also when describing a problem involving dates, please don't use regional or language-specific formats like `dd/mm/yyyy`. It sounds rich coming from a Canadian living in America, but it's much better to use unambiguous formats.

Comment: You're welcome, Eric! The dates are derived from the column dueDate.

Comment: I've changed the dates format @Aaron Bertrand, thanks for the tip!

Comment: What about if you have more then 4 records and dates for the same parcel? And why IDMain is always 254? This table seems to be pretty wrong.

Comment: @jMarcel Oh, I understand. You have to provide the entire logic that you are using in order we can help you. You are asking for a lot of code (work and time to invest) without any try and support. In any case I don't understand how you discrimine unique records and what kind of order do you expect. I won't downvote but yes close because I think this answer must be updated with a lot of work and information.

Comment: The table is not wrong @Leandro Bardelli. As you can see in the table I've provided, there are 5 columns for the dates (d1 to d5) to be filled in chronological order with the dates from the column dueDate, because in its business logic was defined that there are a maximum of 5 possible dates. And id_main is not always 254, please, check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some messed up data you have there!

```
SELECT 
  id_main, 
  id_operation, 
  id_cli, 
  MAX(name), 
  MIN([duedate]), 
  MAX(value), 
  MAX(debtshare), 
  MAX(address),
  MAX(CASE WHEN rnvd = 1 THEN id_parcel END) as id_parcel,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rnd = 1 THEN [duedate] END) as d1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rnd = 2 THEN [duedate] END) as d2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rnd = 3 THEN [duedate] END) as d3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rnd = 4 THEN [duedate] END) as d4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rnd = 5 THEN [duedate] END) as d5
  -- MAX([type])
FROM
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_main, id_operation, id_cli ORDER BY value DESC) as rnvd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_main, id_operation, id_cli ORDER BY [duedate]) as rnd 
   FROM tbTest
  ) x
GROUP BY id_main, id_operation, id_cli
ORDER BY 1,2,3 DESC
```

Your fiddle didn't have [type] in, but I'm sure you can add it/adjust this to what you have

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2144b6/17

Comment: I had to fix a few typos to get the fiddle to run.

Comment: @Caius Jard, that is exactly what I need! I'm very grateful for your help!!

Comment: @joelcoehoorn yes; I just used it as-was in case it was a more accurate reflection of the database columns than the question! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work, though there's probably a more efficient way:

```
with baseRows as (
    select distinct id_operation, id_cli FROM tbTest
), dueDates as (
    select 
        row_number() over (partition by id_operation, id_cli order by dueDate) as rn,
        id_operation, id_cli, dueDate
    from tbTest x 
)
SELECT f.*, d1.dueDate, d2.dueDate, d3.dueDate, d4.dueDate, d5.dueDate
FROM baseRows b
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbTest WHERE id_operation = b.id_operation and id_cli = b.id_cli) f
INNER JOIN dueDates d1 on d1.id_operation = b.id_operation and d1.id_cli = b.id_cli
     and d1.rn = 1
LEFT JOIN dueDates d2 on d2.id_operation = b.id_operation and d2.id_cli = b.id_cli
     and d2.rn = 2
LEFT JOIN dueDates d3 on d3.id_operation = b.id_operation and d3.id_cli = b.id_cli
     and d3.rn = 3
LEFT JOIN dueDates d4 on d4.id_operation = b.id_operation and d4.id_cli = b.id_cli
     and d4.rn = 4
LEFT JOIN dueDates d5 on d5.id_operation = b.id_operation and d5.id_cli = b.id_cli
     and d5.rn = 5 
ORDER BY id_operation, id_cli
```

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2144b6/13

Note I left `id_main` out of the partitions and joins, because it was the same in every record of the sample data. You may need to put that back in.

Comment: with a little adaptation using your solution, I've reached what I was looking for, I feel honored for your help!